# How to activate "Add existing field"?

Tags: 7, entities

In the section called **Manage fields** within a content type, there is an option called **Add an existing field**. How this field is activated?

Some time ago I installed Drupal 7.38 and I worked with such option. This option was there. I never knew how it appeared there.

Now, I have two new Drupal installations (7.38 and 7.40). None of them shows by default the option called "Add an existing field".

Does the option "Add an existing field" belong to *Drupal core* or to some *contributed module*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add an existing field** is belong to *Drupal core* only.

You are not getting the option to **Add an existing field** because you have not created any field as of now. You cannot add an existing field until you have created it as a new field first. After you have created the new field, you can attach that field to multiple content types using **Add an existing field**

The [Drupal.org documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1577260) does not recommend that you re-use fields:

> "It is recommended to create new fields, rather than reusing existing
>   ones, unless you have a clear reason to do so".

Comment: The link included in your answer no longer includes such recommendation. Instead it now rather explains how to decide between yes or no reusing fields. Maybe you want to adapt that part of your answer also?